# Call a Div Modal on Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog

I made a Modal myself that consists of some css and div . I have a validation, how can I call my div modal when my validation passes? Here's my modal

```
<!-- Start Modal -->
                    <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
                        <div>
                                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Last Name</th>
                                        <td id="modal_lastname"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>First Name</th>
                                        <td id="modal_firstname"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Island</th>
                                        <td id="modal_island"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Region</th>
                                        <td id="modal_region"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Province</th>
                                        <td id="modal_province"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>City</th>
                                        <td id="modal_city"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Barangay</th>
                                        <td id="modal_barangay"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Address</th>
                                        <td id="modal_address"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Gender</th>
                                        <td id="modal_gender"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Birthdate</th>
                                        <td id="modal_birthdate"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="btn" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                    <!-- End Modal -->
```

My Validation. Basically I want to call my model on after "else"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkFields()
{ 
    var a=$('#lastname').val();
    var b=$('#firstname').val();
    var c=$('#island').val();
    var d=$('#region').val();
    var e=$('#province').val();
    var f=$('#city').val();
    var g=$('#barangay').val();
    var h=$('#address').val();
    var i=$('#gender').val();
    var j=$('#birthdate').val();

    if (a==null || a=="", b==null || b=="", c==null || c=="", d==null || d=="", e==null || e=="", f==null || f=="", g==null || g=="", h==null || h=="", i==null || i=="", j==null || j=="")
    {
      //alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
      return false;
    }
    else
       //I want to call my Modal here
}
</script>
```

Here's my CSS

```
<style type="text/css">


.modalDialog {
position: fixed;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
opacity:1;
pointer-events: auto;
```

}

```
.modalDialog > div {
width: 400px;
position: relative;
margin: 10% auto;
padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
background: #fff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
background: #606061;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 25px;
position: absolute;
right: -12px;
text-align: center;
top: -10px;
width: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
border-radius: 12px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the css display property instead of opacity for toggling the modal. 
Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkFields()
{ 
    var a=$('#lastname').val();
    var b=$('#firstname').val();
    var c=$('#island').val();
    var d=$('#region').val();
    var e=$('#province').val();
    var f=$('#city').val();
    var g=$('#barangay').val();
    var h=$('#address').val();
    var i=$('#gender').val();
    var j=$('#birthdate').val();

    if (a==null || a=="", b==null || b=="", c==null || c=="", d==null || d=="", e==null || e=="", f==null || f=="", g==null || g=="", h==null || h=="", i==null || i=="", j==null || j=="")
    {
      //alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
      return false;
    }
    else
       $("#openModal").show();
}
</script>
```

Css(you can keep a certain opacity if you want):

```
.modalDialog {
position: fixed;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0.8;
display: none;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
pointer-events: none;
}
```

This way you can do:

```
$(".close").click(function() {
     $("#openModal").hide();
});
```

Comment: Hi. I edited my post. I included the css. show() doesn't work :(

Comment: Of course you can still toggle the modal using the opacity but this might have unintended effects as the display still takes up space in the document even as it isn't seen. With display set to none it won't take up any space.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to get what you're asking. especially without the css. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkFields()
{ 
    var a=$('#lastname').val();
    var b=$('#firstname').val();
    var c=$('#island').val();
    var d=$('#region').val();
    var e=$('#province').val();
    var f=$('#city').val();
    var g=$('#barangay').val();
    var h=$('#address').val();
    var i=$('#gender').val();
    var j=$('#birthdate').val();

    if (a==null || a=="", b==null || b=="", c==null || c=="", d==null || d=="", e==null || e=="", f==null || f=="", g==null || g=="", h==null || h=="", i==null || i=="", j==null || j=="")
    {
      //alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
      return false;
    }
    else
        $('#modal_lastname').html(a);
        $('#modal_firstname').html(b);
        $('#modal_island').html(c);
        $('#modal_region').html(d);
        $('#modal_province').html(e);
        $('#modal_city').html(f);
        $('#modal_barangay').html(g);
        $('#modal_address').html(h);
        $('#modal_gender').html(i);
        $('#modal_birthdate').html(j);


        $(".modalDialog").css("opacity":"1.0");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Didn't work Sir. I have a form. And I wan't the modal to pop up after the validation passes.

Comment: I have changed the last line to update the opacity of the model to 1.0. Try it now.